# C# kill a timer together with its event handler

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

When I turn of my program, at some point, I want to kill a System.Timers.Timer and also its elapsed event handler. This is because this event handler contains some functions with large timeouts and before going on with the shutdown procedure I want to make sure it is killed. How do I kill the event handler execution if it is in progress? Maybe better, how do I kill the timer's thread? How do I get a handler or something to timer's thread?
The code is nothing fancy. To start:

```
timer_txrx = new System.Timers.Timer();  
timer_txrx.Elapsed += OnTimerTxRxEvent;  
timer_txrx.Interval = TIMER_TXRX_INTERVAL;
```

To stop:

```
timer_txrx.Stop(); timer_txrx.Dispose(); timer_txrx = null;
```

But, of course, the above is not enough to stop it. I want not only to prevent it triggering a new "elapsed" event, but also kill the current event handler execution, I want to abort it's thread.

Comment: Post your code snippet to get some idea about what you're doing and how

Comment: spawn: _timer_txrx.Elapsed += OnTimerTxRxEvent;_ kill: _timer_txrx.Elapsed -= OnTimerTxRxEvent;_

Comment: @TaW: timer_txrx.Elapsed -= OnTimerTxRxEvent apparently only prevents a new call of the handler but it seems to me that it does not kill the one in progress

Comment: That is correct. The current Tick will run through but no further will be called. (Unless you had added it more than once.) - You can't kill a running method from the outside. You can add a `if (!timer.Enabled) return;` at strategic points in the code..

Comment: @TaW: I know I can't kill a function. That's the reason I want to abort the thread. This will give a ThreadAbortException in the function and this I can handle. Question is how to kill the thread, how to obtain a handler to timer's thread.